# Embed html table tag in email intent android

Tags: android, html-email

I am working on a concept in which I have to embed **html table tag** in email body.I tried some work around code it's working fine in **2.2 and 2.3** OS versions but the same code is not working in latest  OS versions like 4.0 etc.

I also tried `Spannable and Html.fromHtml()`but it's also not working.

Here is my code which is working on 2.2 and 2.3 OS versions:

```
//SEND EMAIL
    private void sendEmail(String imageUri) throws WriterException{
        //....................Prepare share email data............................. 
        int itemNumber=0;
        titleBuffer=new StringBuffer();

        titleBuffer.append("<html><body><table border="+"1"+"><tr border="+"0"+"><th>Item number</th>"+
                "<th>Barcode</th>"+"<th>Product name</th>"+"<th>Quantity</th></tr>");
        for(int i=0;i<_productList.size();i++){
            itemNumber=i+1;
            titleBuffer.append("<tr border="+"0"+"><td>"+itemNumber+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+_productList.get(i).getProductBarcode()+"</td>"+"<td>"+_productList.get(i).getProductName()+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+_productList.get(i).getProductQuantity()+"</td></tr>");

            /*titleBuffer.append("<tr border="+"0"+"><td>"+itemNumber+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+_productList.get(i).getProductBarcode()+"</td>"+"<td>"+_productList.get(i).getProductName()+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+_productList.get(i).getProductQuantity()+"</td>"+"<td>"+
                    "<img src="+"/'data:image/png;base64, "+generateBarcodeImage(GenerateBarcode.encodeAsBitmap(_productList.get(i).getProductBarcode(), 
                            BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, 600, 300))+"/'/></td></tr>");*/
        }

        titleBuffer.append("</table></body></html>");

        SpannedString bar = new SpannedString(titleBuffer.toString());

        if(_productList.size()==0){
            titleBuffer.append("NA");
        }
        //..........................................................................

        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/html");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Shopping List");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,titleBuffer.toString());
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, emailImageUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
    }
```

Also find the attached image which proves it worked in 2.2 and 2.3 OS versions.

[image]

Comment: have you tried Html.from()?

Comment: Yes, I tried but no effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code :-

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The Subject");
shareIntent.putExtra(
Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
    .append("<p><b>Some Content</b></p>")
    .append("<small><p>More content</p></small>")
    .toString())
);
```

for more info see below link:-

[android - How to format the text as table in email body of email client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154790/android-how-to-format-the-text-as-table-in-email-body-of-email-client)

[How to send HTML email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007540/how-to-send-html-email)

http://blog.iangclifton.com/2010/05/17/sending-html-email-with-android-intent/

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the email client which is handling it. Not all the email clients supports all the HTML tags.Atleast Gmail doesn't support it. Its works only for basic tags, like, `<b>`, `<i>` etc.It doesn't work for especially `<img>` tag.

See these so posts for more info,

[Sending html email in android using <table>, etc. - is there really no relatively built-in Intent way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787171/sending-html-email-in-android-using-table-etc-is-there-really-no-relativel)

[Android, How to send HTML email and force Android to send it through G-Mail not other applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447445/android-how-to-send-html-email-and-force-android-to-send-it-through-g-mail-not)

[How to send html content with image through android default email client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136480/how-to-send-html-content-with-image-through-android-default-email-client)