# How to send hyper link

Tags: android

How can i send the hyper link through mail.

```
Intent i = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(getActivity())

        .setText(PageContants.MAIL_CONTENT1+Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + pdfLink+"\"> here </a>")+PageContants.MAIL_CONTENT2).setSubject(PageContants.MAIL_SUBJECT)

        .setType("message/rfc822").getIntent().setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        startActivity(i);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sending this to mail clients like Gmail ?

Comment: yes but the links are no more clickable

Answer (score 0):

Not all the email cleints support all the html tags. Android Gmail client doesn't support it atleast.Its works only for basic tags, like, ,  etc.It doesn't work for especially `<img>`,`<href>` etc tags.

reference,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7787568/1665507

[Android, How to send HTML email and force Android to send it through G-Mail not other applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447445/android-how-to-send-html-email-and-force-android-to-send-it-through-g-mail-not)